# Getting AttributeError when running optuna study

Tags: python, python-3.x, optuna

I am trying to run optimization using `optuna`:

```
study = optuna.create_study(direction='minimize', sampler=optuna.samplers.GridSampler(search_space))
study.optimize(objective, n_trials=20)
```

For which I am getting below error:

`AttributeError: module optuna.samplers has no attribute GridSampler`

`optuna` version is `0.10.0`

Could someone please help me on how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your example:

```
pip install optuna==0.10.0
```

Then:

```
print(dir(optuna.samplers))

#output
['BaseSampler',
 'RandomSampler',
 'TPESampler',
 '__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__',
 'base',
 'random',
 'tpe']
```

I see that we do not have `GridSampler`

You need to upgrade your `optuna`

[optuna.samplers.GridSampler](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/samplers/generated/optuna.samplers.GridSampler.html#optuna-samplers-gridsampler)

---

```
pip install optuna --upgrade

#Successfully installed optuna-3.4.0
```

Now,

```
print(dir(optuna.samplers))

#output
['BaseSampler',
 'BruteForceSampler',
 'CmaEsSampler',
 'GridSampler',
 'IntersectionSearchSpace',
 'MOTPESampler',
 'NSGAIIISampler',
 'NSGAIISampler',
 'PartialFixedSampler',
 'QMCSampler',
 'RandomSampler',
 'TPESampler',
 '__all__',
 '__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__',
 '_base',
 '_brute_force',
 '_cmaes',
 '_grid',
 '_lazy_random_state',
 '_nsgaiii',
 '_partial_fixed',
 '_qmc',
 '_random',
 '_search_space',
 '_tpe',
 'intersection_search_space',
 'nsgaii']
```

Comment: I can see base, random and TPE, but not GridSampler after i executed the `--upgrade` code

Comment: What is your version `optuna` version?

Comment: version is `0.10.0`

Comment: `pip install optuna==3.4.0`

Comment: I uninstalled `optuna` and reinstalled with `3.4.0`. Even then I am getting the same error, and `GridSampler` is not there in the print dir output

Comment: This is very strange.. I am getting it in my print(dir).. please see the above output of my print(dir) in my answer.... I am using python 3.10.. Windows 11

Comment: If you are using Jupyter, please make sure to restart your kernel

Comment: I restarted kernel, strangely it said `no module named optuna`, then I reinstalled it, I get lot of `warning target directory already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement` I then ran the `--upgrade` command, I still get same modulenotfound error

Comment: I would recommend to open a freash new notebook and `pip install optuna==3.4.0`, restart kernel, and then `import optuna`.. then try your code.

Comment: I am still getting those `warning` messages and while importing it says modulenotfound. Not sure what's messed up

Comment: I have 2 questions: (1) Did you try to create a new virtual environment (`conda` based or other, depending on your setup) and install the required versions of packages there? (2) Do you use the correct virtual environment for your notebook?